# search for elements in a 2-D array in vba

Tags: vba

Code: VBA

Suppose there is a 2-D array

counter(1 to 8, 1 to 2) as string

```
A   6

B   7

C   8

D   9

E   10

F   11

G   12

H   13
```

I want to get the corresponding number to the alphabets if I use.

counter("F",2).

how do i do it?

Comment: i used nested for loops to search for the alphabet first, when i find it, "Exit For" is implemented. then the respective number is shown. it is a tedious process as I have hundreds of rows and nested for loop will run 100*2 times, resulting in slowing down of my algorithm.

Comment: if you want to search for alphabet, create a key-value pair. use dictionary. once you load the dictionary.. No inner/ no outer / no loop at at all required get value .

Comment: Can you pls write the code for the given question? would really appreciate it!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  It is a site dedicated to helping overcome specific problems with existing code.  Please put the code you have tried in the original post using the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary or collection is good approach to learn, and I'd recommend reviewing these data structures.

Here's an alternative approach using some built-in VBA functions. Basically it will lookup the ASCII code, and then offset that number to align to with the values you presented earlier, e.g, A-->6.

```
Public Function OffsetChar(ByVal Character As String, _
                           Optional ByVal OffsetValue As Integer) As Integer
    OffsetChar = Asc(UCase(Left(Character, 1))) + OffsetValue
End Function

Public Sub SO_Example()
    Debug.Print OffsetChar("a", -59) ' This will return 6
End Sub
```

It should be very quick as well.